# ASP.NET - scroll screen to previous  position after postBack

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there any way to scroll screen to previous position after DropDownList (or other control) postBack?

Comment: AFAIK, MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback doesn't work on Firefox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the page directive of your aspx

MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"

Comment: +1 you may add which unfortunately does not work most of the time :)

Comment: Ok.. AFAIK, **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback** doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: @Chris: i didn't work for me in many scenarios and i then had to to try other client side solutions. :) http://forums.asp.net/t/1216885.aspx/2/10

Comment: I agree that it's wonky.  It works in FF9.  And I've tested 4 or 5 IE machines here (IE8 and IE9, the IE8 boxes are XP and Win7).  Some of the IE boxes work fine, others do not.  But it's not consistent in which ones do/do not work.  Different events cause the feature to work, or not work.

Comment: I tried this. This didn't work for me when using a table for scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your page load.

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```

Comment: I, personally, never used it on the server side.

Comment: you can do it either way I just forgot about the page directive.  You can also set it globally in the web.config